# How to access variable keys in an associative array in fluid?

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-7.6.x

I assign an associative array `values` to my view in the action controller.

`<f:debug>{values}</f:debug>` outputs the following, which means, the data is in the view.

```
array (3 items)
    63 => 158 (integer)
    49 => 0 (integer)
    164 => 0 (integer)
```

In my fluid template I have a loop over some items. In that loop, I create select fields with the f:form.select viewhelper. The form is not bound to an object, I can not use the property argument. But I want to reflect the current (last selected) value of each of the select fields.

Each select is named `filter_{loopItem.uid}`.

`<f:debug>{values.63}</f:debug>` outputs `158 (integer)` which is correct, too.
If I set `value={values.63}` in the value argument of the f:form.select viewhelper, the corresponding option is selected in filter_63.

What I want to do, is use the uid as index for the filters array, so that I can write something like `value={values.{loopItem.uid}}` and the select selects the corresponding option. But this does not work, debug outputs NULL.

{values.63} with a constant 63 works fine.
Even an alias mapped {index: loopItem.uid} with {values.index} results in NULL.

How can I substitute the fixed 63 by a variable value based on the loopItem.uid?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is only possible out of the box with TYPO3 8 or you can try VHS https://viewhelpers.fluidtypo3.org/fluidtypo3/vhs/5.0.1/Variable/Get.html

Comment: Nice to know that TYPO3 8 can handle it.